# Best way to do asynchronous processing in PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, asynchronous

I need to build a system (in PHP) that does massive queries on MSSQL to retrieve the result as follows:

I have 10 independent queries that I need to run when a user visits a page (some are massive). What is the most scalable solution to running 3 queries in parallel (7 in queue) and when a query is finished, run another from the queue?

I need the page to load instantly, and as the query finishes, show the user the response of that query (the order is not so important).

I took into consideration: AJAX, beanstalkd, NodeJS, libevent and Gearman or implement it as a web service in java (using threads and parallel processing).

PS : I also found `AJAX PUSH ENGINE (APE - http://www.ape-project.org/)` and `xRML (http://www.xrtml.org/)` but never used it

Comment: Someone changed SQL to MSSQL in your question (so I tagged it as SQL-Server) what type of database are you actually using?

Comment: Sorry , it was me .. I'm using MSSQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NOTE** *this answer is for the first revision of the question that did not ask for MSSQL in particular*

MySQL supports asynchronous queries via MySQLi when using the mysqlnd driver.

Passing `MYSQLI_ASYNC` (available with mysqlnd) as `$resultmode` argument to `mysqli_query()` performs the query asynchronously. `mysqli_poll()` and `mysqli_reap_async_query()` is then used to get results from such queries.

Also see http://blog.ulf-wendel.de/?p=170 for an in-depth discussing of parallel, background and asynchronous fetch ideas for mysqlnd.

Comment: Can you also use this for MSSQL?

Comment: @MattEllen no. The ext/mysqli is for MySql databases. I dont know whether MSSQL supports async queries through ext/mssql. It doesnt look like it from the documentation.

Comment: Anyway... will the future bring full suport for async in PHP ? Or push to the browser ?

Comment: @pufos if by that you mean will php support threads anytime soon, then the answer is No. However, you can implement a Job Queue in native PHP through forking. See https://github.com/kore/njq. Server push can be implemented via websockets. Google has a couple of server implementations. I do not know how mature those are though.

Comment: @Gordon but .. how is facebook making it almost realime with push notifications ? I don;t think they're using SetTimeinterval ...

Comment: @pufos On your profile page? Inspect it with Firebug and you will see it polls the server for updates in regular intervals. They are not using Server push. And they likely have some sort of Message queue in the back to handle the polling. I doubt there is any PHP involved in that process. Or if, its only a glue language to delegate to the Message Queue.

Comment: @Gordon I know that PHP is not involved in that, but I was very curious how did they do that ? I know they are using Hadoop and Hbase (htable) but the realtime like process only with Javascript can be achieved right ?

Comment: @pufos see https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/the-underlying-technology-of-messages/454991608919 for some details.

Comment: They only talking about Hbase structure, not how the realtime was implemented

Answer (score 1):

My solution would be to put the query jobs onto beanstalk message queue to be serviced by a background process (daemon?).  As the jobs are finished the result sets are cached somewhere.

The loaded page uses AJAX (in a kind of polling loop - e.g, request every 10 seconds) to find out from a server-side application if the results are ready (which it does by looking in the cache for the result set).

As the results become available, the server-side app sends them to the page which loads them into a div.

Comment: You mean AJAX long pull ? The AJAX is the only solution to retrieve the result and dynamically update the page ?